# Помогите с телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Ситуация такая: изучаю питон 3-ий день. Посмотрел видео курс из 5 часов. Посчитал, что можно приступить к простому, написанию телеграм бота. Я хочу, чтобы он не только ссылки писал, но и погоду. А когда прошу его написать погоду, то либо не работает команда старт, то бесконечно просит вводит города, а если введу не правильный город, то просто крашает бота. Переписывал некоторые блоки у "ютуберов",  а они нихуя не объясняют и я ничего не понимаю. Можете закидать меня помидорами, но я рил не шарю, но очень хочу научиться!!! Закомментированный блок - это и есть блок с погодой, гори она в аду.  Вот код:

```
import telebot
import pyowm
from telebot import types
owm = pyowm.OWM('мой апи', language = 'ru')
bot = telebot.TeleBot ("мой апи")
can_send_messages = True


@bot.message_handler(commands=['insta'])
def open_insta(message):
    markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btninst = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тык сюда и ты моей инсте", url="я удалил ссылку")
    markup1.add(btninst)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Подпишись", reply_markup=markup1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['vk'])
def open_vk(message):
    markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btnvk = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тык сюда и ты моем вк", url="я удалил ссылку")
    markup1.add(btnvk)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Подпишись", reply_markup=markup1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['stoopid'])
def open_stoopid(message):
    markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btnst = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тык сюда и ты у самого тупого чела", url="я удалил ссылку")
    markup1.add(btnst)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отпишись", reply_markup=markup1)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ты вышел из раздела, жду команды!")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def reec(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"""Я туповат пока что и не всегда понимаю, что ты хочешь от меня,но скоро я буду имбой 
        Тем не менее, я не могу: 
        /weather - узнать погоду (не работает, хз почему)
        /start снова поприветсвую тебя и спрошу кто ты
        про /menu ты уже знаешь
        /insta - узнать мою инсту 
        /vk - узнать мой вк
        /stoopid - самый тупой чел
        /stop - выход из раздела
        Пока функционал заканчивается!""")


#@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
#def pogoda(message):
    #get_message_bot = message.text.strip().lower()
    #if get_message_bot == "weather":
        #observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)
        #w = observation.get_weather()
        #temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
        #answer1 = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status() +'\n'
        #answer1 += " Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) +'\n'
        #if temp < 10:
        #   answer1 +='На улице холодно, шо пиздец, оденься, как зимой!'
        #elif temp < 15:
        #   answer1 +='На улице чет холодновато, оденься теплее!'
        #elif temp < 20:
        #   answer1 += "На улице в принципе тепло, но в шортах не рекомендую выходить"
        #elif temp > 20:
        #   answer1 += "На улцие жара, шо пиздец "
        #else:
        #   answer1 += "Введи норм город или другю команду"
        #bot.send_message(message.chat.id,answer1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def privet(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    btn1=types.KeyboardButton("/start")
    btn2=types.KeyboardButton("/menu")
    btn3=types.KeyboardButton("/vk")
    btn4=types.KeyboardButton("/insta")
    btn5=types.KeyboardButton("/stoopid")
    btn6=types.KeyboardButton("/stop")
    btn7=types.KeyboardButton("/weather")
    markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7)
    stic = open('sticker.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, stic)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

        #bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я тебя не понимаю, введи /menu , чтобы все понять!!")   
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def deafult(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я тебя не понимаю, введи '/menu' , чтобы все понять!!")



bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пользователь написал боту (нажал на кнопку ReplyKeyboardMarkup, которая отправляет в чат от имени пользователя "заготовку") `weather` - `if get_message_bot == "weather":`
бот переходит в режим погода. Ок.

Текст сообщения пользователя, `message.text` передаётся в `owm.weather_at_place()` как место - `observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)`.

Так как же бот не будет падать, если функция получения погоды пытается найти погоду в месте weather?

Почему бы не сделать для погоды отдельную команду `@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])`?

Тогда:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def cmd_city(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи город')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, city)  # ожидает следующий шаг

def city(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ищу погоду в городе {city}'.format(city=message.text))
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.get_weather()
    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
    answer1 = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status() + '\n'
    answer1 += " Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + '\n'
    if temp < 10:
        answer1 += 'На улице холодно, шо пиздец, оденься, как зимой!'
    elif temp < 15:
        answer1 += 'На улице чет холодновато, оденься теплее!'
    elif temp < 20:
        answer1 += "На улице в принципе тепло, но в шортах не рекомендую выходить"
    elif temp > 20:
        answer1 += "На улцие жара, шо пиздец "
    else:
        answer1 += "Введи норм город или другю команду"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer1)
```

Либо, без хэндлера на команду:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def text(message):
    if message.text == 'weather':
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи город')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, city)


def city(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ищу погоду в городе {city}'.format(city=message.text))
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.get_weather()
    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
    answer1 = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status() + '\n'
    answer1 += " Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + '\n'
    if temp < 10:
        answer1 += 'На улице холодно, шо пиздец, оденься, как зимой!'
    elif temp < 15:
        answer1 += 'На улице чет холодновато, оденься теплее!'
    elif temp < 20:
        answer1 += "На улице в принципе тепло, но в шортах не рекомендую выходить"
    elif temp > 20:
        answer1 += "На улцие жара, шо пиздец "
    else:
        answer1 += "Введи норм город или другю команду"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer1)
```

UPD:

1. Обработчики (Handlers) - это функции с общей подписью:

`handler(request, response)`

Ожидается, что обработчик будет использовать информацию из запроса (например, путь) либо для заполнения объекта ответа данными для отправки, либо для прямой записи в выходной поток через экземпляр ResponseWriter, связанный с запросом. Если обработчик выполняет запись в выходной поток, то сервер не будет пытаться выполнить дополнительную запись, т.е. выбор записи прямо в обработчик или нет - «все или ничего».

[о декораторах](https://habr.com/ru/post/141411/)

2. в данном случае `send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи город')` это переменная.
3. расположение команд не имеет значения, просто удобно видеть, например /start первым блоком кода, разве нет?
4. [bot.register_next_step_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py) ожидает ввод и переходит к другому шагу передавая ему данный ввод.
5. кнопка которая бы возвращала пользователя на этап назад - например создать функцию которая описывает главную клавиатуру и при `if message.text == 'назад':` вызывать данную функцию
6. да, можно под одним хэндлером можно расположить несколько функций.
   6.1 верно, сначала идёт cmd_city(), после city()

Comment: Спасибо. Если не трудно, можешь ответить еще на пару вопросов? Хэндлер за что отвечает? "send" - это переменная или функция? Имеет ли значение порядок расположения команд(старт, может быть, должен быть только вверху или только снизу, например)?  Что такое бот.регистр.некстстеп? Как создать кнопку, которая бы возвращала пользователя на этап назад или эта кнопка не обязательна? Спасибо еще раз огромное) На самом деле очень трудно что то выучить, разобраться в чем то, когда возникают вопросы, а в гугле нет мельчайших деталей в ответе на мой вопрос

Comment: Под одним хэндлером можно расположить несколько функций и они будут работать, а так же важен порядок расположения функций, я правильно понимаю? (Говорю про cmd_city и city)

Comment: дополнил свой ответ. блок UPD

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья, спасибо огромное)

Comment: А следующий шаг - это функция city?

Comment: Могу ли я как то тебе в лс писать, если буду возникать какие проблемы с питоном?

Comment: напишите свой логин в телеграм

Comment: @dursinear - вот он